# How to select specific datetime-indidices by intraday time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a timeindex and need all of the timeindices in it which are between these daytimes:
(EDIT: its multiple days)

```
a,b = "07:21:39","22:00:01" 

index_ = DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-20 10:21:00', '2019-08-20 10:22:00', '2019-08-20 10:23:00', '2019-08-20 10:24:00', '2019-08-20 10:25:00', '2019-08-20 10:26:00', '2019-08-20 10:27:00', '2019-08-20 10:28:00', '2019-08-20 10:29:00', '2019-08-20 10:30:00', '2019-08-20 10:31:00', '2019-08-20 10:32:00', '2019-08-20 10:33:00', '2019-08-20 10:34:00', '2019-08-20 10:35:00', '2019-08-20 10:36:00', '2019-08-20 10:37:00', '2019-08-20 10:38:00', '2019-08-20 10:39:00', '2019-08-20 10:40:00', '2019-08-20 10:41:00', '2019-08-20 10:42:00', '2019-08-20 10:43:00', '2019-08-20 10:44:00', '2019-08-20 10:45:00', '2019-08-20 10:46:00', '2019-08-20 10:47:00', '2019-08-20 10:48:00', '2019-08-20 10:49:00', '2019-08-20 10:50:00', '2019-08-20 10:51:00', '2019-08-20 10:52:00', '2019-08-20 10:53:00', '2019-08-20 10:54:00', '2019-08-20 10:55:00', '2019-08-20 10:56:00', '2019-08-20 10:57:00', '2019-08-20 10:58:00', '2019-08-20 10:59:00', '2019-08-20 11:00:00', '2019-08-20 11:01:00', '2019-08-20 11:02:00', '2019-08-20 11:03:00', '2019-08-20 11:04:00', '2019-08-20 11:05:00', '2019-08-20 11:06:00', '2019-08-20 11:07:00', '2019-08-20 11:08:00', '2019-08-20 11:09:00', '2019-08-20 11:10:00', '2019-08-20 11:11:00', '2019-08-20 11:12:00', '2019-08-20 11:13:00', '2019-08-20 11:14:00', '2019-08-20 11:15:00', '2019-08-20 11:16:00', '2019-08-20 11:17:00', '2019-08-20 11:18:00', '2019-08-20 11:19:00', '2019-08-20 11:20:00', '2019-08-20 11:21:00', '2019-08-20 11:22:00', '2019-08-20 11:23:00', '2019-08-20 11:24:00', '2019-08-20 11:25:00', '2019-08-20 11:26:00', '2019-08-20 11:27:00', '2019-08-20 11:28:00', '2019-08-20 11:29:00', '2019-08-20 11:30:00', '2019-08-20 11:31:00', '2019-08-20 11:32:00', '2019-08-20 11:33:00', '2019-08-20 11:34:00', '2019-08-20 11:35:00', '2019-08-20 11:36:00', '2019-08-20 11:37:00', '2019-08-20 11:38:00', '2019-08-20 11:39:00', '2019-08-20 11:40:00', '2019-08-20 11:41:00', '2019-08-20 11:42:00', '2019-08-20 11:43:00', '2019-08-20 11:44:00', '2019-08-20 11:45:00', '2019-08-20 11:46:00', '2019-08-20 11:47:00', '2019-08-20 11:48:00', '2019-08-20 11:49:00', '2019-08-20 11:50:00', '2019-08-20 11:51:00', '2019-08-20 11:52:00', '2019-08-20 11:53:00', '2019-08-20 11:54:00', '2019-08-20 11:55:00', '2019-08-20 11:56:00', '2019-08-20 11:57:00', '2019-08-20 11:58:00', '2019-08-20 11:59:00', '2019-08-20 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

already tried this:

```
a, b=   pd.to_datetime(a, format='%H:%M:%S').time,     pd.to_datetime(b, format='%H:%M:%S').time

selected_idx     = pd.Series(index_.time, index=index_)
selected_idx     = selected_idx.loc[(selected_idx>=a) & (selected_idx<=b)]
```

but it results in:

```
  File "D:\Main.py", line 946, in main_bars
   selected_idx     = selected_idx.loc[(selected_idx>=a) & (selected_idx<=b)]

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 529, in wrapper
    res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 247, in comparison_op
    res_values = comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, lvalues, rvalues)

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 57, in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
    result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)

  File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 96, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Otherwise I'd be happy with another way to do this^^

**Updates on what doesnt work:**

**Update (what also doesnt work):**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

a,b = pd.to_datetime("07:21:39", format='%H:%M:%S').time, pd.to_datetime("22:00:01" , format='%H:%M:%S').time

index_ = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-20 10:21:00', '2019-08-20 10:22:00', '2019-08-20 10:23:00', '2019-08-20 10:24:00', '2019-08-20 10:25:00', '2019-08-20 10:26:00', '2019-08-20 10:27:00', '2019-08-20 10:28:00', '2019-08-20 10:29:00', '2019-08-20 10:30:00', '2019-08-20 10:31:00', '2019-08-20 10:32:00', '2019-08-20 10:33:00', '2019-08-20 10:34:00', '2019-08-20 10:35:00', '2019-08-20 10:36:00', '2019-08-20 10:37:00', '2019-08-20 10:38:00', '2019-08-20 10:39:00', '2019-08-20 10:40:00', '2019-08-20 10:41:00', '2019-08-20 10:42:00', '2019-08-20 10:43:00', '2019-08-20 10:44:00', '2019-08-20 10:45:00', '2019-08-20 10:46:00', '2019-08-20 10:47:00', '2019-08-20 10:48:00', '2019-08-20 10:49:00', '2019-08-20 10:50:00', '2019-08-20 10:51:00', '2019-08-20 10:52:00', '2019-08-20 10:53:00', '2019-08-20 10:54:00', '2019-08-20 10:55:00', '2019-08-20 10:56:00', '2019-08-20 10:57:00', '2019-08-20 10:58:00', '2019-08-20 10:59:00', '2019-08-20 11:00:00', '2019-08-20 11:01:00', '2019-08-20 11:02:00', '2019-08-20 11:03:00', '2019-08-20 11:04:00', '2019-08-20 11:05:00', '2019-08-20 11:06:00', '2019-08-20 11:07:00', '2019-08-20 11:08:00', '2019-08-20 11:09:00', '2019-08-20 11:10:00', '2019-08-20 11:11:00', '2019-08-20 11:12:00', '2019-08-20 11:13:00', '2019-08-20 11:14:00', '2019-08-20 11:15:00', '2019-08-20 11:16:00', '2019-08-20 11:17:00', '2019-08-20 11:18:00', '2019-08-20 11:19:00', '2019-08-20 11:20:00', '2019-08-20 11:21:00', '2019-08-20 11:22:00', '2019-08-20 11:23:00', '2019-08-20 11:24:00', '2019-08-20 11:25:00', '2019-08-20 11:26:00', '2019-08-20 11:27:00', '2019-08-20 11:28:00', '2019-08-20 11:29:00', '2019-08-20 11:30:00', '2019-08-20 11:31:00', '2019-08-20 11:32:00', '2019-08-20 11:33:00', '2019-08-20 11:34:00', '2019-08-20 11:35:00', '2019-08-20 11:36:00', '2019-08-20 11:37:00', '2019-08-20 11:38:00', '2019-08-20 11:39:00', '2019-08-20 11:40:00', '2019-08-20 11:41:00', '2019-08-20 11:42:00', '2019-08-20 11:43:00', '2019-08-20 11:44:00', '2019-08-20 11:45:00', '2019-08-20 11:46:00', '2019-08-20 11:47:00', '2019-08-20 11:48:00', '2019-08-20 11:49:00', '2019-08-20 11:50:00', '2019-08-20 11:51:00', '2019-08-20 11:52:00', '2019-08-20 11:53:00', '2019-08-20 11:54:00', '2019-08-20 11:55:00', '2019-08-20 11:56:00', '2019-08-20 11:57:00', '2019-08-20 11:58:00', '2019-08-20 11:59:00', '2019-08-20 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


print(len(index_))

gra = pd.Series(np.nan, index=index_)
print(gra)
print(len(gra.between(a,b)))
```

results in the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\....p.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(len(gra.between(a,b)))

 File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4364, in between
    lmask = self >= left

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 529, in wrapper
    res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

  File "c:\users\trent\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 253, in comparison_op
    res_values = method(rvalues)

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

**Update (what also doesnt work2):**

```
a,b =    datetime.datetime.strptime("09:21:39", "%H:%M:%S").time ,  datetime.datetime.strptime( "10:00:01", "%H:%M:%S").time
index_ = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-20 10:21:00', '2019-08-20 10:22:00', '2019-08-20 10:23:00', '2019-08-20 10:24:00', '2019-08-20 10:25:00', '2019-08-20 10:26:00', '2019-08-20 10:27:00', '2019-08-20 10:28:00', '2019-08-20 10:29:00', '2019-08-20 10:30:00', '2019-08-20 10:31:00', '2019-08-20 10:32:00', '2019-08-20 10:33:00', '2019-08-20 10:34:00', '2019-08-20 10:35:00', '2019-08-20 10:36:00', '2019-08-20 10:37:00', '2019-08-20 10:38:00', '2019-08-20 10:39:00', '2019-08-20 10:40:00', '2019-08-20 10:41:00', '2019-08-20 10:42:00', '2019-08-20 10:43:00', '2019-08-20 10:44:00', '2019-08-20 10:45:00', '2019-08-20 10:46:00', '2019-08-20 10:47:00', '2019-08-20 10:48:00', '2019-08-20 10:49:00', '2019-08-20 10:50:00', '2019-08-20 10:51:00', '2019-08-20 10:52:00', '2019-08-20 10:53:00', '2019-08-20 10:54:00', '2019-08-20 10:55:00', '2019-08-20 10:56:00', '2019-08-20 10:57:00', '2019-08-20 10:58:00', '2019-08-20 10:59:00', '2019-08-20 11:00:00', '2019-08-20 11:01:00', '2019-08-20 11:02:00', '2019-08-20 11:03:00', '2019-08-20 11:04:00', '2019-08-20 11:05:00', '2019-08-20 11:06:00', '2019-08-20 11:07:00', '2019-08-20 11:08:00', '2019-08-20 11:09:00', '2019-08-20 11:10:00', '2019-08-20 11:11:00', '2019-08-20 11:12:00', '2019-08-20 11:13:00', '2019-08-20 11:14:00', '2019-08-20 11:15:00', '2019-08-20 11:16:00', '2019-08-20 11:17:00', '2019-08-20 11:18:00', '2019-08-20 11:19:00', '2019-08-20 11:20:00', '2019-08-20 11:21:00', '2019-08-20 11:22:00', '2019-08-20 11:23:00', '2019-08-20 11:24:00', '2019-08-20 11:25:00', '2019-08-20 11:26:00', '2019-08-20 11:27:00', '2019-08-20 11:28:00', '2019-08-20 11:29:00', '2019-08-20 11:30:00', '2019-08-20 11:31:00', '2019-08-20 11:32:00', '2019-08-20 11:33:00', '2019-08-20 11:34:00', '2019-08-20 11:35:00', '2019-08-20 11:36:00', '2019-08-20 11:37:00', '2019-08-20 11:38:00', '2019-08-20 11:39:00', '2019-08-20 11:40:00', '2019-08-20 11:41:00', '2019-08-20 11:42:00', '2019-08-20 11:43:00', '2019-08-20 11:44:00', '2019-08-20 11:45:00', '2019-08-20 11:46:00', '2019-08-20 11:47:00', '2019-08-20 11:48:00', '2019-08-20 11:49:00', '2019-08-20 11:50:00', '2019-08-20 11:51:00', '2019-08-20 11:52:00', '2019-08-20 11:53:00', '2019-08-20 11:54:00', '2019-08-20 11:55:00', '2019-08-20 11:56:00', '2019-08-20 11:57:00', '2019-08-20 11:58:00', '2019-08-20 11:59:00', '2019-08-20 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) 

gra    = pd.Series(index_, index=index_)
gra_ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip( gra.index.date, gra.index.time))  
gra = pd.Series(index_.time, index=index_)
# ==> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

**Note (might be helpful):**

I noticed that the ".time" on the timevalues a & b might be guilty. Because if I remove it, the error suddenly says:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Is it a DatetimeIndex? then `df.between_time(a,b)`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: @ALollz  Does it for every day at the same time (because my index contains thousands of days) or do I have to iterate over every single day

Comment: Nope, that's the magic of it. It literally just subsets between the times, regardless of days.

Comment: @ALollz sounds good, but I am getting the Error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'. (See Updated Question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from .time -> this is a method.

Using .time() with the braces fixed the problem^^